# How do i convert docx into json for firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, docx

I have quotes stored in Docx but i want to convert it to JSON, so I don't have to add every individual quote manually in firebase

here is the [docx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1paZxgnSnQY3wsikPfFiwRBlf5pTu6NUv/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110245666828154676370&rtpof=true&sd=true) file

here is a SS of how my database looks like and how do I want to store quotes in firebase

[image]

[image]

now, how can I convert the docx file into JSON so I don't have to add every quote individually in firebase?

> Note:-  right now I have few quotes but I will add more, will it
> cause any issue in the future

Comment: check this : https://thenewstack.io/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-json-formatted-text/