# I want my google sheet format to match the json format for firebase

Tags: json, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have quotes in my google sheets what I want is to format the google sheet in a way that matches my existing firebase JSON format but tbh I don't know JSON, previously I was just adding every single quote manually and it was taking too much time to copy the quote from the google sheets into firebase

so someone suggests me automate the thing by exporting the existing google sheet into JSON but the only issue I'm facing is that I want to the converted format of JSON to be the same as my already existing firebase database JSON format but when I export it to JSON the format is not the same so the thing I have to change is in the format how I add quotes in google sheets

Here are my [google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sx-FOG6vdga-w3iZvUOTpq3S2WQvt5DDqIZbkW6rhmE/edit?usp=sharing)

here is my already JSON format of firebase which I get when I did a export to JSON in firebase,[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6Ul9qblAc5SkGhC2N3-yMmpGqRxmaGP/view?usp=sharing) // and I want this exact format for the google sheets so the exported JSON looks like this original one

[Here](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheet-to-json-formatted-text/) is the way how I'm converting the google spreadsheet into JSON

and

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541410/how-do-i-convert-docx-into-json-for-firebase) is the previous question where I got the answer on how to convert google sheet into json

Here is a database reference how it looks right now
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand `the only issue I'm facing is that I want to the converted format of JSON to be the same as my already existing firebase database JSON format but when I export it to JSON the format is not the same so the thing I have to change is in the format how I add quotes in google sheets`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect?

Comment: sorry for the grammer, i dont have the exact input smaple but i want  this exact output https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6Ul9qblAc5SkGhC2N3-yMmpGqRxmaGP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: this is the appscript code i was get previoulsy https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pamelafox/1878143/raw/6c23f71231ce1fa09be2d515f317ffe70e4b19aa/exportjson.js?utm_source=thenewstack&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=platform

Comment: but if you want to know which code im cureently getting please read the asnwer bellow

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all. This is a [double post](https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/v7ki0w/how_do_i_format_google_spreadsheet_to_match_with/)...

I created a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UG1wdfCOTkJnN-1cnWhZCBXhOpyfzEEuCT-xF63xn48/edit?usp=sharing) with your data because you could not get it to work on based on the instructions.

**Original script:**

```
function quotes(){
  //Change these values
  const sheetname = 'Data'
  const driveFolderId = 'dsfdsfsfsdfsdf'
  const filename = 'philisophical'
  const dateSuffix = true
  const dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

  //Rest of the code
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  const values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  const object = {
    Quotes: {}
  }

  values.forEach(quote => {
    const [q, title] = quote
    object.Quotes[q] = {
      title
    }
  })

  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), dateFormat)
  const driveFileName = filename + (dateSuffix) ? ` | ${date}` : ""
  const json = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(driveFolderId).createFile(`${driveFileName}.json`, json)
  
}
```

**Adapted for the sample sheet:**
Uses current sheet and leaves out the date part.

```
function quotes() {
  const filename = 'philisophical'

  //Rest of the code
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  const values = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

  const object = {
    Quotes: {}
  }

  values.forEach(quote => {
    const [q, title] = quote
    object.Quotes[q] = {
      title
    }
  })

  const json = JSON.stringify(object, null, 2);
  DriveApp.createFile(`${filename}.json`, json)

}
```

Comment: but now im not getting the export button on my google sheet , but it was previously awailable when i used this code https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pamelafox/1878143/raw/6c23f71231ce1fa09be2d515f317ffe70e4b19aa/exportjson.js?utm_source=thenewstack&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=platform